# Slack in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to integrate opening Slack in Sharepoint Online.
How can I add a webpart that will open Slack in the iframe and add a link to the group / channel in the path, which will be taken from the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embed web part for embedding iframes within SharePoint Online.

Alternatively, you could build your own SPFx web part.